# Restlet http handler failed: The "/" Character isn't allowed in a media type parameter name

Tags: java, header, content-type, restlet

I'm using a third part code to send post(form) request to my apache server. However, I'm keep getting this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Content Type could not be read.
at org.restlet.engine.header.ContentType.<init>(ContentType.java:155)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerCall.getRequestEntity(ServerCall.java:243)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpRequest.getEntity(HttpRequest.java:503)
at org.restlet.engine.application.Decoder.beforeHandle(Decoder.java:124)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:204)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:155)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:211)
at org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.handle(ApplicationHelper.java:84)
at org.restlet.Application.handle(Application.java:384)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:431)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:648)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:431)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:648)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:155)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:211)
at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:406)
at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:72)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:152)
at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpServerHelper$1.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:73)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:677)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:649)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$DefaultExecutor.execute(ServerImpl.java:158)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.handle(ServerImpl.java:433)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.run(ServerImpl.java:398)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The "/" character isn't allowed in a media type parameter     name.
at org.restlet.engine.header.ContentTypeReader.readValue(ContentTypeReader.java:178)
at org.restlet.engine.header.ContentType.<init>(ContentType.java:148)
... 41 more
Error while handling an HTTP server call: 
Error while handling an HTTP server call
```

I googled it, and I found out that it is an error message from restlet header content handler. Any idea how to solve this problem ? I've already tried add annotation for post like:

```
@Post("application/json")
```

or add request headers like:

```
        ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("...");
        Series<Header> headers = (Series<Header>) cr.getRequestAttributes().get(
                                         "org.restlet.http.headers");
        if (headers == null) {              
            headers = new Series(Header.class); 
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");                
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authCode");
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, x-requested-with, content-type");
        } 

        if (headers != null) {              
            headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");                
            cr.getRequestAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", headers); 
        }
```

I hope someone could give the answer to solve this problem or give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when using Restlet annotations, don't use the full media type: @Post("json") does the job.

Then, I don't understand why you include "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", etc, that is to say CORS headers inside your client code. Such code is not subject to cross domains restrictions.

Then, if you intend to send an entity to the server, the content-type is actually "hosted" by the sent representation. Use the Representation#setMediaType method.

In order to be clearer, you can have a look at this page (http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.2/core/http-headers-mapping), it lists the headers that are mapped with the Restlet API.
Any headers already mapped must not be set up manually.

To my mind, your client code must be as simple as :

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("...");
Representation entity = ...;
entity.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
cr.setEntity(entity);
```

Feel free to ask for more details.